# How to get such result on google?

Tags: seo, google

Sometimes when I google something, I notice that some websites are shown with some several pages as results. Like in the picture here :

[image]

Does anyone know how to get such results on google search please ? What should I add to my web site to get it appear like this ?

I have been looking on rich snippets but I'm not sure it's this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are called [site links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). The short answer is that is not up to you if Google shows them in a brand search or not.

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

Nonetheless, there are a few things you can work in order to make them appear:

1. Use a unique brand name (if it's possible)
2. Make sure you rank first for your brand name
3. Use a simple&clear browsing directory
4. Submit a XML sitemap to Google Search Console
5. Build a good internal linking strategy
6. Avoid duplicate content